# addServlet error in Tomcat7 deployment

Tags: servlets, websocket, tomcat7, web.xml

I created a web application using :
- HTML 5
- WebSocket (with Tomcat 7)
- Spring
- Hibernate

The issue is during the dpeloyment of my war in Tomcat 7 :

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig parseWebXml
Grave: Erreur d'Úvaluation (parse) dans le fichier web.xml de l'application Ó jn
di:/localhost/mywebapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jndi:/localhost/mywebapp/WEB-INF/web.xm
l; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 12; Error at (11, 12) : org.apache.catalina.dep
loy.WebXml addServlet
```

Here my web.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">

<display-name>My WebApp</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Welcome</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>websocket.UrlWebSocketServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Welcome</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/websocket/welcome</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

</web-app>
```

Here my Servlet (WebSocket class) :

```java
public class UrlWebSocketServlet extends WebSocketServlet {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UrlWebSocketServlet.class);

@Override
protected boolean verifyOrigin(String origin) {
    log.trace("Origin: {}", origin);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected StreamInbound createWebSocketInbound(String subProtocol, HttpServletRequest request) {
    return new WebSocketConnection();
}

private static class WebSocketConnection extends MessageInbound {

    @Override
    protected void onOpen(WsOutbound outbound) {
        log.info("Conexión abierta");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onClose(int status) {
        log.info("Conexión cerrada");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBinaryMessage(ByteBuffer byteBuffer) throws IOException {
        log.warn("No se soportan mensajes binarios");
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No se soportan mensajes binarios");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTextMessage(CharBuffer charBuffer) throws IOException {
        final String user = charBuffer.toString();
        log.debug("Mensaje recibido: {}", user);
        getWsOutbound().writeTextMessage(CharBuffer.wrap("Hola " + user + " desde WebSocket"));
    }
}
}
```

EDIT :

Here my pom.xml's part for Tomcat jar :

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.29</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-coyote</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.29</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.29</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Thank's a lot :)

Chris

Comment: I suggest to change the locale to English so that you get error messages in English. This way you will find/get much sooner answers on Google or Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi, thank's for your response. I translated in google : 'Evaluation error (parse) in the file web.xml of the application
di:/localhost/mywebapp/WEB-INF/web.xml' and try with google. No more results for my issue...

Comment: I have the solution : I have to delete the catalina jar from my lib folder, eems to resolve this issue...

Comment: pauli answer is correct.
This is the explanation <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646959/difference-between-maven-scope-compile-and-provided-for-jar-packaging">--></a>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.29</version>
</dependency>
```

should say:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.29</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```