# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/openspaces/core/GigaSpace

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat, gigaspaces

I'm trying to use Gigaspaces with Spring! I have two eclipse projects. A spring rest-service that consumes a space of Gigaspaces (the other eclipse project). I have a master eclipse project where I have both projects.

My problem is that I want to deploy my rest-service on my Tomcat v7.0 it crashes and show me:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.payulatam.prototype.services.IClientService com.payulatam.prototype.controllers.ClientController.clientService; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/openspaces/core/GigaSpace;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1122)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:983)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1660)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Seems that tomcat can't found gigaspace's jars. But I'm including them on my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.payulatam.prototype</groupId>
<artifactId>rest-service</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>rest-service</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.payulatam.prototype</groupId>
    <artifactId>PayUBank</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <gsVersion>9.6.2-9900-RELEASE</gsVersion>
    <spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jackson.version>1.9.10</jackson.version>
    <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gigaspaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>gs-openspaces</artifactId>
        <version>${gsVersion}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.payulatam.prototype</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>rest-service</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified that com.gigaspaces will be **provided by the server or executor service** you are using when you put `<scope>provided</scope>` in the dependency declartion for com.gigaspaces, which you are missing on the classpath as per the stacktrace said.

The most probable case here is that it is **not** bieng provided by the server, so try to delete/change the line `<scope>provided</scope>` to `<scope>compile</scope>` in your pom for the dependency declaration for the Gigaspaces library; So maven will be the one that provides it.

Help from: [Difference between `compile` and `provided` scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646959/difference-between-maven-scope-compile-and-provided-for-jar-packaging)

Comment: Oh! Thank you @DirkyJerky! :D :D :D That was the reason!

Answer (score 0):

**Change this section in your pom.xml**

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gigaspaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>gs-openspaces</artifactId>
        <version>${gsVersion}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**To**

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gigaspaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>gs-openspaces</artifactId>
        <version>${gsVersion}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Just for your own understanding before you make the changes check in your deployed war file if you have the gs-openspaces.xxx.jar file. You will not see it there. Now make the changes rebuild and redeploy and again check this time you should see the jar file.

**[Maven Dependency Scope explained](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)**

Also see the links provided by DirkyJerky in his answer.