# Maven Scope for Lombok (Compile vs. Provided)

Tags: java, maven, lombok

I recently found out that the `lombok.jar` ends up in our final artifact, which shouldn't be necessary. In my understanding `lombok` is compile-time only.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.14.4</version>
</dependency>
```

But when I set it to scope provided, I get strange behavior in unit tests. They crash with `ClassNotFoundExceptions` then when trying to resolve

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/svv/esp/serviceimpl/dataimport/common/validation/LongValidator
```

Which maven scope is in general used for `lombok`?

I'm using Oracle JDK build 1.8.0_25-b17 on MacOSX 10.9.

Comment: well, you may need to set the scope to test. as for your question, i usually set it to compile but it just because i'm to lazy to bother with it :p

Answer (score 179):

Lombok should be used at the `provided` scope (see the [official docs](https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven)).

The reason (as has been stated in the comments) is that lombok is a compile-time-only tool. That is, it is not needed at runtime **at all**. By making the scope `provided`, you make the lombok libraries available to the compiler but it is **not** a dependency of your compiled jar. As such, your final jar will not depend on lombok and it does not need to be included in any deployment, which reduces the dependencies and size of your deployables.

Comment: As a side note, cause this might be confusing for a lot of people: maven scope `compile` means it's available at compile time and at run time. If scope is `provided` it's only available at compile time. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646959

Comment: I, too, was confused of this `compile` versus `provided` thing in java when i used lombok [here](https://asciinema.org/a/VDw2z6tqFsR1aAinR9tQM8QiV). Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 6):

One can work with `compile` and `true` for `<optional/>`.

```
<scope>compile</scope>
<optional>true</optional>
```

See [Maven – Optional Dependencies and Dependency Exclusions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html).

Comment: https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven Official Lombok documentation says to use the `provided` scope

Answer (score 0):

You must configure the spring-boot-maven-plugin to exclude the lombok jar from the Spring executable jar file.

Here is an example plugin configuration from a pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <addResources>true</addResources>
        <classifier>module</classifier>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            </exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score -1):

Usually `compile`. `provided` is for jars that are usually shipped with the application server that will host the application. If you don't want the jar in the final application, it is maybe best to use the maven plugin rather than the jar directly: http://awhitford.github.io/lombok.maven/lombok-maven-plugin/index.html

Comment: +1 for the lombok plugin, didn't know that.
But still, it isn't obvious to me why provided does not work in this case. It should be available during compile time and not be necessary anymore in later phases.

Comment: To be certain I would need to at least see the `LongValidator` class that is reported missing and probably other elements in the pom, but most probably the problem with `provided` is that Lombok must perform its work when compilation takes places, or in runtime. If you do not include it nor generate the Lombok code when compiling, your class will be as if is was not processed by Lombok.

Comment: To clarify further: Lombok is not just a library, it is a processor that modifies the code when compilation takes place. So you need to execute it when compiling, if you switch it to `provided` scope this will not happen by default (you can force maven to run the lombok processor adding `-Dexec.classpathScope="compile"`to the command line.)

Comment: This answer just isn't correct. The plugin doesn't need to be used, and the documentation says provided scope