# Identifying Dependencies in Maven

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

We have a Spring boot project build with maven. Now I have to identify dependencies which are important and which not which should be build into the jar file and which not. I found a command "mvn dependency:analyze" which shows Unused and Used dependencies.

For example under Unused dependencies I can see lombok is listed,Unused dependencies should be removed I read, but if I remove it I can not do mvn clean install because lombok is used in our project.

My question is how can I clean up the pom safe way? And exclude dependencies from the jar. I am new to maven.

this is used undeclared dependencies:

```
   [WARNING] Used undeclared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.1.12.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:test
[WARNING]    org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.11.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.3.13.Final:compile
[WARNING]    org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:6.4.3:compile
[WARNING]    org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[WARNING]    org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.29:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.zalando:problem-spring-common:jar:0.25.2:compile
[WARNING]    org.keycloak:keycloak-adapter-core:jar:4.6.0.Final:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    com.github.vanroy:spring-data-jest:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.10:compile
[WARNING]    net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:jar:6.3:compile
[WARNING]    javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.1.11.RELEASE:test
[WARNING]    org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-adapter-core:jar:4.6.0.Final:compile
[WARNING]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.10.1:compile
[WARNING]    org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[WARNING]    org.zalando:problem-violations:jar:0.25.2:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.1.11.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.1.12.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.1.11.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    io.searchbox:jest-common:jar:6.3.1:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[WARNING]    org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.11.1:test
[WARNING]    org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:jar:3.1.12.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.1.11.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.1.11.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.1.11.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.zalando:problem:jar:0.23.0:compile
[WARNING]    org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.23.4:test
[WARNING]    org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-security-adapter:jar:4.6.0.Final:compile
[WARNING]    org.keycloak:keycloak-core:jar:4.6.0.Final:compile
[WARNING]    junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[WARNING]    jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[WARNING]    org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.27:compile
[WARNING]    javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
[WARNING]    org.zalando:jackson-datatype-problem:jar:0.23.0:compile
```

This is unused undeclared:

```
[WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.10:compile
[WARNING]    org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:jar:1.5.1:compile
[WARNING]    org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-security:jar:1.5.1:compile
[WARNING]    org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:jar:1.3.0.Final:provided
[WARNING]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:provided
[WARNING]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:test
[WARNING]    com.github.vanroy:spring-boot-starter-data-jest:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    de.dentrassi.elasticsearch:log4j2-mock:jar:0.0.1:runtime
[WARNING]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    com.stripe:stripe-java:jar:19.26.0:compile
[WARNING]    org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-starter:jar:4.6.0.Final:compile
[WARNING]    mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:8.0.18:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.200:compile
```

And the tree:

```
  [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.1.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.3.13.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.23.2-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.9.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.1.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.1.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.1.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.1.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.1.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.1.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.29:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.27:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.27:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.27:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.18.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.1.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.1.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.1.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:jar:3.1.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.10.5:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.elasticsearch.client:transport:jar:6.4.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:reindex-client:jar:6.4.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client:jar:6.4.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:lang-mustache-client:jar:6.4.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- com.github.spullara.mustache.java:compiler:jar:0.9.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:percolator-client:jar:6.4.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:parent-join-client:jar:6.4.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.elasticsearch.plugin:rank-eval-client:jar:6.4.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.10:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.elasticsearch.plugin:transport-netty4-client:jar:6.4.3:compile
[INFO] |        +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.43.Final:compile
[INFO] |        +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.43.Final:compile
[INFO] |        +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.43.Final:compile
[INFO] |        +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.43.Final:compile
[INFO] |        +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.43.Final:compile
[INFO] |        +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.43.Final:compile
[INFO] |        \- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.43.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.1.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.10:compile (optional) 
[INFO] +- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.webjars:swagger-ui:jar:3.37.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.webjars:webjars-locator-core:jar:0.35:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.8.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-security:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-common:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-models:jar:2.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:jar:2.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-integration:jar:2.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-core:jar:2.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.github.classgraph:classgraph:jar:4.8.69:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:jar:1.3.0.Final:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] +- io.github.jhipster:jhipster-framework:jar:3.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.1.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:jar:6.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:28.1-jre:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.18:compile
[INFO] +- org.zalando:problem-spring-web:jar:0.25.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.zalando:problem-violations:jar:0.25.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.zalando:problem-spring-common:jar:0.25.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.29:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.zalando:problem:jar:0.23.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.zalando:jackson-datatype-problem:jar:0.23.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.zalando:faux-pas:jar:0.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.lz4:lz4-java:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.7.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.11.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.23.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.9.16:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.1.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.1.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.1.11.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.6.3:test
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.vanroy:spring-boot-starter-data-jest:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.vanroy:spring-data-jest:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:6.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-core:jar:6.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-secure-sm:jar:6.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-x-content:jar:6.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-smile:jar:2.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:jar:2.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-grouping:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-join:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-memory:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial-extras:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial3d:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-suggest:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-cli:jar:6.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:5.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.carrotsearch:hppc:jar:0.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.tdunning:t-digest:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.elasticsearch:jna:jar:4.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.searchbox:jest:jar:6.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.searchbox:jest-common:jar:6.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:jar:4.4.12:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient:jar:4.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] +- de.dentrassi.elasticsearch:log4j2-mock:jar:0.0.1:runtime
[INFO] +- com.google.maps:google-maps-services:jar:0.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:3.14.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.17.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.1.8:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.stripe:stripe-java:jar:19.26.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-starter:jar:4.6.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-2-adapter:jar:4.6.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-adapter-core:jar:4.6.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.keycloak:keycloak-core:jar:4.6.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.keycloak:keycloak-common:jar:4.6.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.60:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.keycloak:keycloak-authz-client:jar:4.6.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.10:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.12:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.keycloak:spring-boot-container-bundle:jar:4.6.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-security-adapter:jar:4.6.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.keycloak:keycloak-adapter-spi:jar:4.6.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.keycloak:keycloak-adapter-core:jar:4.6.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.60:compile
[INFO] +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.3.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.1.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.3.2:test
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:8.0.18:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.undertow:undertow-core:jar:2.0.27.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.xnio:xnio-api:jar:3.3.8.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.xnio:xnio-nio:jar:3.3.8.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  +- io.undertow:undertow-servlet:jar:2.0.27.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.undertow:undertow-websockets-jsr:jar:2.0.27.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.spec.javax.websocket:jboss-websocket-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:compile (optional) 
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] \- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.200:compile
```

Comment: Can you post the output of  `mvn dependency:tree` and `mvn dependency:analyze` ? Even snippets or redacting `com.hasan.employer` entries would help provide answers.

Comment: Hi, I posted the outcomes you wanted

Comment: The most important part is not there the pom.xml file... and in spring boot to say something is not needed is an interesting approach? Do you know when it's used or not?

Comment: That is part of my Question how can I verify if something is used or not? For example lombok is used in our project but the command says it is unused...

Answer (score 1):

You should learn about Maven's dependecy scopes:
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope

For example with Lombok a `provided` scope should be used as explained in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29385921/maven-scope-for-lombok-compile-vs-provided/38454162#38454162).

Comment: I will look at this. Thanks. One question what is the criteria on which base should I decide to exclude or not for a dependency ?

Comment: There is no acid test.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean you just need to know. For example I see you have H2 as a dependency. You're using it for unit tests, right? Then the scope should be `test` as your app doesn't need it at runtime. I really can't explain it any better than the apache manual did. However, I don't think you should exclude anything unless you're having problems with it.