# I cannot package maven-plugin-api into uber jar using maven-shade-plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

My pom.xml looks as follows:

```xml
  <!-- Use shade plugin for uber jar -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
    <configuration>
    <filters>
     <filter>
       <artifact>maven-plugin-api</artifact>
       <includes>
         <include>org/apache/maven/**</include>
       </includes>
     </filter>
     </filters>
      <shadedArtifactAttached>false</shadedArtifactAttached>
      <transformers>
        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
          <mainClass>com.abc.def.ver.main.Main</mainClass>
        </transformer>
      </transformers>
      <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

But when my jar is created I get the following error while running main:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/plugin/descriptor/PluginDescriptor
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2688)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3035)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3005)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1771)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.plugin.descriptor.PluginDescriptor
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 7 more
```

I also have dependency as

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.5</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

in my pom.

1. How does it work? I don't have `maven-plugin-api` in my local repository. Is it taking it from my Maven (application) lib folder to run it because normally it runs perfectly. And if it is taking from my maven folder I have maven-3.3.1 and the specified version is 3.2.5.
2. How can I make it work?

Comment: Why would you like to do this? Apart from that i assume that you have a `maven-plugin-api` somewhere in your repository....

Comment: I am basically converting an maven plugin to a java project so it can be executed on a remote PC without maven being installed. I need this for that. If it would help it works perfectly when I run my main from eclipse.

Comment: $ java -classpath "C:\Users\works\maven-plugin-api\3.2.5\maven-plugin-api-3.2.5.jar" -jar "C:\tools\main\target\main-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"

If it helps even this does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `<scope>provided</scope>` you are saying that the related artifact does not need to be included, because it will "magically" be available in the classpath.

See [Difference between maven scope compile and provided for JAR packaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646959/difference-between-maven-scope-compile-and-provided-for-jar-packaging) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the [`maven-shade-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) will ignore all provided dependencies. As such, the `maven-plugin-api` dependency, which has a `provided` scope, will not be kept.

This is expected: [provided dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) are supposed to be made available at runtime by the container. There are two solutions:

- Remove the provided scope from the dependency declaration. It will be then included inside the uber jar.
- Keep the provided scope but make the `maven-plugin-api` artifact available at runtime by adding it to the classpath when your application is launched.

Comment: Sorry Got too Excited doesn't work. 

keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope:
When true, dependencies are kept in the pom but with scope 'provided'; when false, the dependency is removed.

This is a bit weird statement. Have you done this before?
I tried  <keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>true</keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope> as well as this  <keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>false</keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>
Jar is still the same and provided are not included. But that is the correct diagnosis. How do I make it work. I don't want to change scope to compile.

Comment: @user1615664 Yes, this parameter only affects the dependency reduces POM. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I shifted to maven-assembly-plugin. It did the job for me. Thanks for your help.