# Running a simple java Servlet gives Class is not a Servlet error

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a simple Java servlet project which I am running via maven tomcat plugin.Hitting the url, I get this error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Class in.vshukla.MyServlet is not a Servlet

java.lang.ClassCastException: in.vshukla.MyServlet cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet
```

The servlet class is

```
import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class MyServlet implements Servlet {
    .
    .
    .
    public void service(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = servletResponse.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Hello, world!</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        out.close();
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

This is accompanied by a simple web.xml file.

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
     <servlet>
         <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>in.vshukla.MyServlet</servlet-class>
     </servlet>
     <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I have cross checked the war file generated. I am attaching the output of tree command on the war file.

```
.
|-- META-INF
`-- WEB-INF
    |-- classes
    |   |-- in
    |   |   `-- vshukla
    |   |       `-- MyServlet.class
    |   `-- spring
    |       `-- spring_config.xml
    |-- lib
    |   |-- javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
    |   `-- my-data-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    `-- web.xml

7 directories, 5 files
```

I am building this using maven.
The following is the pom.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <parent>
    <groupId>in.vshukla</groupId>
    <artifactId>my</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>my-api</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <javax.version>3.1.0</javax.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>in.vshukla</groupId>
      <artifactId>my-data</artifactId>
      <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>${javax.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Even though the class MyServlet is implementing a javax Servlet, I am getting this error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please paste the import section please ?

Comment: What if you do instead  public class MyServlet  extends HttpServlet {

Comment: @Sarker : Added import section. It gives the same error if I extend HttpServlet.

Comment: Just remove `javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar` from your `.war` file as specified in the answer by IanLovejoy, and your problem will go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You typically will not want to include javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar in your .war. It will be provided by the framework. If two classes are loaded by different class loaders, even if they have the same package and name, they will be considered distinct classes.

Comment: Might want to state it more emphatically, as in, *DON'T* include `javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar`. You should *NEVER* include it in the `.war` file.

Comment: @Andreas haha yes, good suggestion, I guess I am sometimes polite to the point of obscuring my point. Perhaps a middle ground - "you _should not_..."

Comment: Okay. How do I prevent it from being included in the war?

Comment: @venky That depends on how it got in there in the first place. You haven't shared your build script. If using Maven, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646959/difference-between-maven-scope-compile-and-provided-for-jar-packaging

Comment: @venky Assuming you are building the .war from a directory, remove it from that source directory.

Comment: @Andreas : Added the pom.xml file. I am using maven for generating it.

Comment: @venky Then add `<scope>provided</scope>`.