# javax.servlet.ServletException: Class com.mq.sample.Hello is not a Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to create simple login application.I have created one login page and one servlet but it is giving the ServletException

here is my sample code.

```
public class Hello extends HttpServlet{

@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException{  
        try{  

        response.setContentType("text/html");  
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

        String username=request.getParameter("username"); 
        String password=request.getParameter("password");
        out.println("hello");

        if(username.equals("xyz")&&password.equals("password"))
        {
            HttpSession session=request.getSession();  
            session.setAttribute("uname",username);
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/Home.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
        else
        {
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.html");
            out.println("<h4>Plz provide correct Username or password</h4>");
            rd.include(request,response);
        }


        out.close();  

                }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  
    }
```

this code is giving the following Exception:
I am not getting why this.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Class com.mq.sample.Hello is not a Servlet

org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mq.sample.Hello cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show your import statements. What package is `HttpServlet` in?

Comment: Check how many different servlet.jar files you have in your deployment - it could be that it's being loaded by two different classloaders

Comment: import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

Comment: only one jar file is there

Comment: Are you using maven?

Comment: Try giving com.mq.sample.hello instead of com.mq.sample.Hello when you invoke the servlet, since you have given the url pattern as '/hello' for the servlet.

Comment: do you have the servlet-api.jar?

Comment: just remove `javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar` it look like same issue:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35954202/running-a-simple-java-servlet-gives-class-is-not-a-servlet-error

Comment: @ShreeNaath , oh please no! your comment solution is really not related.

Comment: yes. I am using maven @soorapadman

Comment: Could  you share it so that we can sorted out?

Comment: NoClassDefinationFoundException is giving...@ShreeNaath

Comment: @Atul,, just delete unnecessary jar, having servlet-api.jar only is enough.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error from Tomcat, refer to [this link](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.0/org/apache/catalina/core/StandardWrapper.java#1085). So the thing is that you have servlet jar conflict in your classpath.
Remove javax.servlet-api.jar from classpath and do this.
 [image]