# How to exclude some dependency in maven-compiler-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, classpath

Guys I need to find out some way to include or exclude dependency while compile my code in maven (maven-compiler-plugin), I don't want to include all dependency in my class path, just few of them which will be used by java class file to be compile.

Is there any to do this  ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Can you give an example? Why would Maven's standard 'exclusions' mechanism not work for your requirement?

Comment: You can use the "scope" element. See the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646959/difference-between-maven-scope-compile-and-provided-for-jar-packaging

Comment: Thanks for comment guys, My requirement is like :I have Class A, which should compiled two times with same dependency but different version of it(Two different jar almost same implementation with few changes). hence I need one dependency at a time two compile my Class A.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the scope of the dependency to provided.  This will make maven assume that the dependencies will be available at run-time.
e.g.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>group-a</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifact-b</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

It is explained much better here -

[Dependency scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope)

Comment: Thanks for answer, please refer my requirement from my comment in question , I know fundamental of dependency scope, I need to specify dependency in my maven compiler plugin some how. I hope you get it.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks, I was looking for this.