# Add dependecy to Maven and set to $CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib

Tags: java, matlab, maven, tomcat, classloader

I'm using Matlab MCR in web project so I imported these dependecies to pom.xml

```
<!-- Matlab client tool library -->
    <!--  <dependency>
            <groupId>DataConcatenation</groupId>
            <artifactId>DataConcatenation</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency> -->
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>DataConcatenator</groupId>
            <artifactId>DataConcatenator</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency> -->
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>DataConversion</groupId>
            <artifactId>DataConversion</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>DataConverter</groupId>
            <artifactId>DataConverter</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>DataConcatenation</artifactId>
                    <groupId>DataConcatenation</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>DataConcatenator</artifactId>
                    <groupId>DataConcatenator</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>DataConversion</artifactId>
                    <groupId>DataConversion</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

The first problems is that I have to exclude the other tree dependencies even if I use only DataConverter, But I need only dataConverter and this library doesn't have other dependecies.
The second and most important problem is this error:

```
Threw exception in ZipAndMat::createZipAndMat: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library /usr/v81/bin/glnxa64/libnativedl.so already loaded in another classloader
```

I read a lot of guide and I understand that I have to put this jar into $CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib so all the class loader share the same jar.
But how can I add this dependecy to the above path? This is the first time that I have to implement this configuration. I use tomcat on my server and deploy project through war file.
Thanks

Comment: If need to specify a dependency from a path, you can use system dependencies https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies , but I am not sure that this is what you want.

Comment: I need to have native library shared between all classLoader, I already have this dependecy in maven

Comment: Related: [*Is $CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib a real feature in Tomcat?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58159342/642706)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place the jar into `$CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib`, and then specify in your [POM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Project_Object_Model) the dependency's `<scope>` as `provided`:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>DataConverter</groupId>
        <artifactId>DataConverter</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            ...
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

This method is often used for jars which contain [JDBC drivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) when running on Tomcat; the jdbc jar is placed in `$CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib` (so all [WAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format))s can find it), yet each project list’s the JDBC jar as a dependency with `provided` as the scope.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646959/difference-between-maven-scope-compile-and-provided-for-jar-packaging) for more information on `provided`.

Comment: from Tomcat documentation https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html. I used `provided` and I put library into $CATALINA_HOME/lib it seems to be work. Thanks