# Error Creating Bean in Spring, dependency is declared in pom, spring cannot find class

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to Inject a rest client into a class, but for some reason spring is failing to create the bean.

First off all, I have the dependency declared in my POM.XML, and the project builds fine:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>event-service-common</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But when spring tries to run, and create the bean I've declared in dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="eventClient" class="com.company.client.EventServiceRestClient">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="http://localhost:9353"/>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="v1"/>
</bean>
```

I get the following stack of errors:

```
Aug 31, 2016 1:59:41 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
    SEVERE: Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'auditLogController' defined in file [/Users/tshibley/spog/spog/target/classes/com/company/controller/AuditLogController.class]: Post-processing failed of bean type [class com.company.controller.AuditLogController] failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class [com.company.controller.AuditLogController] for resource metadata: could not find class that it depends on
    at     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:940)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class [com.company.controller.AuditLogController] for resource metadata: could not find class that it depends on
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:935)
    ... 28 more


    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/company/client/EventServiceRestClient;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionUtils.java:710)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalFields(ReflectionUtils.java:652)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:351)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:330)
    ... 30 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.client.EventServiceRestClient
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    ... 37 more

    Aug 31, 2016 1:59:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'auditLogController' defined in file [/Users/tshibley/PS/spog/spog/target/classes/com/company/controller/AuditLogController.class]: Post-processing failed of bean type [class com.company.controller.AuditLogController] failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class [com.company.controller.AuditLogController] for resource metadata: could not find class that it depends on
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:940)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class [com.company.controller.AuditLogController] for resource metadata: could not find class that it depends on
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:935)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/company/client/EventServiceRestClient;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionUtils.java:710)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalFields(ReflectionUtils.java:652)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:351)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:330)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.client.EventServiceRestClient
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    ... 37 more

Aug 31, 2016 1:59:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet  threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.client.EventServiceRestClient
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionUtils.java:710)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalFields(ReflectionUtils.java:652)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:351)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:330)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:935)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare thedependency as `provided` you are telling maven that the dependnecy will be available in runtime, but that jar will not be packaged in your project. You likely want a `compile` scope, which will be included in your classpath (for instance, packaged into a WAR).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>event-service-common</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

See: [Difference between maven scope compile and provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646959/difference-between-maven-scope-compile-and-provided-for-jar-packaging)

Comment: This was one of the first things I tried, but when I remove `provided` I run into a different error:

Comment: `javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "javax.servlet.jsp.JspApplicationContext.getExpressionFactory()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader) of the current class, org/apache/jsp/login_jsp, and the class loader (instance of org/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/realm/ClassRealm) for the method's defining class, javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext, have different Class objects for the type javax/el/ExpressionFactory used in the signature`

Comment: I tried searching for the issue, but nothing out there seemed to address my problem. One interesting thing to note is that if I remove the event-service-common declaration from my POM.xml altogether, I don't run into this issue (Although the `eventServiceRestClient` doesn't work obviously

Comment: It looks like `event-service-commons` brings a transitive dependency on `javax-servlet:servlet-api`. You should either exclude it in your pom, or declare it as `provided`in `event-service-commons`, since the Jave EE classes will be provided by your application server.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You injected `auditLogController` in `EventServiceRestClient`, but you haven't define `auditLogController`

You need to define `auditLogController`

Comment: `auditLogController` is currently being created in `<context:component-scan base-package= "com.company.controller"/>` and I have verified that it is working by running the whole project without `EventServiceRestClient`, and `auditLogController` works (other than the functionality provided by `EventServiceRestClient` of course)

Comment: @TrevorShibley Do you inject `auditLogController` in `EventServiceRestClient`?

Comment: No, the other way around, I inject `EventServiceRestClient` into `AuditLogController`