# compile/provided scopes for War/Jar packagings in Maven

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Talking about Maven, I know that:

1. a *compile* dependency is not included in the final outcome when packaging is *jar*
2. on the other hand, it is being included if packaging is *war*
3. a *provided* dependency is never included in the final outcome neither with *jar* nor with *war* packaging

For example, in the case of a *compile* scoped dependency in a *jar* packaging, at compile time Maven will simply fetch the dependency from local/remote repositories, without including such dependency in the final artifact.

If all this is correct, my questions are:

1) Who is then usually providing a *compile* scoped dependency at runtime for a *jar* artifact?

2) What is the difference between a *provided* dependency in a *jar* and a *war* packaging then?

Comment: See the concept of executable JARs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven, and see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646959/difference-between-maven-scope-compile-and-provided-for-jar-packaging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Who is then usually providing a compile scoped dependency at runtime for a jar artifact?

If you integrate the [Maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to your `pom.xml`, the **dependencies with scope `compile` will be packed to the assembly, together with your projects artifact**. The dependencies with scope `provided` are not added:

Here is an example. It assumes that there is an specific assembly descriptor (`projectAssembly.xml`), not a default one.

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>${artifactId}-${version}-distribution</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/projectAssembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assembly</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

> 2) What is the difference between a provided dependency in a jar and a war packaging then?

In both cases, the dependencies aren't added.