# Apache Flink: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, apache-flink, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to follow this [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/java/get-started-exercise-fh.html) but when I try to compile it, I have this error:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class com.amazonaws.services.kinesisanalytics.aws
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/source/SourceFunction
```

The error is due this code:

```
    private static DataStream<String> createSourceFromStaticConfig(StreamExecutionEnvironment env) {
        Properties inputProperties = new Properties();
        inputProperties.setProperty(ConsumerConfigConstants.AWS_REGION, region);
        inputProperties.setProperty(ConsumerConfigConstants.STREAM_INITIAL_POSITION, "LATEST");

        return env.addSource(new FlinkKinesisConsumer<>(inputStreamName, new SimpleStringSchema(), inputProperties));
    }
```

And I suppose this is the problematic line:

```
  return env.addSource(new FlinkKinesisConsumer<>(inputStreamName, new SimpleStringSchema(), inputProperties));
```

This are my maven dependencies:

[image]

What could be wrong? any dependencies, version?

Note: If I comment the problematic line, the program run without problem. Also to note, this error also appears on certain Kafka (`aws-kafka`) samples; I was shown the same error with the *amazonaws.kafka.samples.CustomMM2ReplicationPolicy* class.

POM file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>as</groupId>
    <artifactId>a</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <geotools.version>21-SNAPSHOT</geotools.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
        <flink.version>1.6.2</flink.version>
        <kda.version>1.0.1</kda.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:force-shading</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.slf4j:*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>log4j:*</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <!-- Do not copy the signatures in the META-INF folder.
                                    Otherwise, this might cause SecurityExceptions when using the JAR. -->
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.amazonaws.services.kinesisanalytics.aws</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.locationtech.jts</groupId>
            <artifactId>jts-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-geojson</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-geojsondatastore</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-main</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-kinesisanalytics-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${kda.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kinesis_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-kinesisanalytics-flink</artifactId>
            <version>${kda.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Make sure you are using correct (compatible) libraries (double check the `flink` version).

Comment: Do you mean the version of the POM file? I'm using the same of the AWS example

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
    <version>${flink.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The scope is `provided`. This means, that your program expects the library to be accessible during the runtime, but it can't find it anywhere.

`NoClassDefFoundError` means it was accessible during the compile-time, but not during the execution.

---

**Change the scope to `compile`** in order to resolve the issue:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
    <version>${flink.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

*Also, you can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646959/difference-between-maven-scope-compile-and-provided-for-jar-packaging) for more technical info.*

Answer (score 12):

For me the solution of @aran doesn't work. If you use IntelliJ, you can set the [Add dependencies with "provided" scope to classpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ku0Jk.png)-option in the Run/Debug Configurations instead.

Credits go to ElvesLab (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gtv4mnpGfI0, 13:38)

Also mentioned in https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/try-flink/datastream/#running-in-an-ide

Comment: yes, this actually did the trick for me as well!

Comment: This worked for me on IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1 (Ultimate Edition). Thanks!