# Why getting "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPException" in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, unboundid-ldap-sdk

Why getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPException` in SpringBoot even added `unboundid-ldapsdk` maven dependency in pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.unboundid/unboundid-ldapsdk -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
            <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Are you able to see `unboundid-ldapsdk` jar in the maven dependencies section ?

Comment: Yes, I am able to see the `unboundid-ldapsdk-4.0.10.jar` in maven dependencies section. thanks @Ashishkumar Singh

Comment: Do you use this for unit testing ?

Comment: no, while starting application getting above error. thanks @Sachith Dickwella

Comment: Try changing <scope>test</scope> to <scope>provided</scope>

Comment: Yes working..Thank you. But what is the difference between test & provided under scope? @Sachith Dickwella

Comment: This answer would be helpful on that question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646959/difference-between-maven-scope-compile-and-provided-for-jar-packaging

Answer (score 0):

Ensure to update the [dependency scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) from `test` to `provided` as per your requirement:

```
...
<scope>test</scope>
...
```