# Maven not loading dependency on local artifact

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have created my own jar file and want to connect it to another project as a dependency.
Inside the jar has its own pom file with dependencies.
When connecting jar with system scope, I have a problem - maven does not load the dependencies jar.

Maybe i forgot some plugin when building jar?

**How can I make maven load dependencies from a local jar?**

**POM my Jar file**

```
<groupId>ru.qa.eso</groupId>
<artifactId>push-qa</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0-alfa</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>PushQA</name>

<properties>
    <selenide.version>5.2.3</selenide.version>
    <rest-assured.version>3.3.0</rest-assured.version>
    <cucumber.version>4.2.0</cucumber.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.4</lombok.version>
    <logback.version>1.3.0-alpha4</logback.version>
    <jul-to-slf4j.version>1.7.25</jul-to-slf4j.version>
    <allure.version>2.9.0</allure.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M3</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <aspectjweaver.version>1.9.2</aspectjweaver.version>
    <allure-maven.version>2.10.0</allure-maven.version>
    <reflections.version>0.9.11</reflections.version>
    <maven.compiler.targer>1.8</maven.compiler.targer>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
        <version>${selenide.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${jul-to-slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-cucumber4-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-selenide</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
        <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
        <version>${reflections.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.mifmif</groupId>
        <artifactId>generex</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>27.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <target>${maven.compiler.targer}</target>
                <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-resource-bundle</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resource-bundle</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <additionalOptions>-Xdoclint:none</additionalOptions>
                <additionalJOption>-Xdoclint:none</additionalJOption>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <argline>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argline>
            <loggerLevel>INFO</loggerLevel>
            <startOnServer>false</startOnServer>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>server</id>
        <properties>
            <argline>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argline>
            <loggerLevel>DEBUG</loggerLevel>
            <startOnServer>true</startOnServer>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

**POM my project, where i want include my jar**

```
<groupId>ru.qa.eso</groupId>
<artifactId>SomeName</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.qa.eso</groupId>
        <artifactId>push-qa</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0-alfa</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: You might want to add your pom.xml file and state more clearly e.g. with variables which Project needs a dependencies from another project. So is Project A your local project and needs something from Project B or do you want to integrate your local project A as a dependency of Project B? With system path you usually get a warning if the path is local. The proper way is to install the project to your local maven repository with maven install then it should resolve..

Comment: Integrate my local project A as a dependency to project B.  
With all the dependencies of the project library A.
mvn install did not help.

I suspect, that i incorrected building jar file.

Comment: That is Why  Posting your pom.xml would give us the Chance to Analyze what is going on

Comment: Sorry. I should have known it.

Comment: *"maven does not load the dependencies jar"* - how do you know? If you get an error, please include it in the question.

Comment: maven dont see any dependecies on my jar file, so i havent any errors.
mvn dependecy tree showed only one dependecies - my jar lib.
I was able to run project, when i use mvn install with pom path, but it is not good way

Comment: Well then, show the output of mvn dependency:tree . The situation you describe is very un-maven; normally if there is even the slightest hint of a problem with a dependency declaration, you get very verbose errors and build failures.

Answer (score -1):

Please use "mvn install" or "mvn clean install" for building the dependency jar. Then add that dependency in dependent project and build.Hopefully it will resolve your issue

Comment: Unfortunatly not(

Answer (score -1):

Can you try by including the scope as compile for dependency as below:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.qa.eso</groupId>
        <artifactId>push-qa</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0-alfa</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Kindly go through following link to get more details regarding scope.
[Scope of Dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646959/difference-between-maven-scope-compile-and-provided-for-jar-packaging)

Hope this was helpful.